# Fast writing to xlsm with xlwings

Tags: python, performance, xlwings, xlsm

I am trying to write a number of floats and strings to an xlsm file using xlwings 0.20.2.

Though the following works, I want it to be faster:

```
sht.range('A1').options(transpose=True).value = [float1, float2]
sht.range('B7').value = string1
sht.range('A4').options(transpose=True).value = [string2, float3]
...
```

I already recognised that

```
sht.range('A1').options(transpose=True).value = [float1, float2]
```

is faster than

```
sht.range('A1').value = float1
sht.range('A2').value = float2
```

Thus my idea was to collect all floats and strings in a single list of lists:

```
output = [[None] * 8, [None] * 8]
output[0][0] = float1
output[0][1] = float2
output[1][8] = string1
...
```

and write that to the Excel sheet.

The problem with that is that each time I hit a `None` in the write-out process, it erases the content of the cell in question (e.g. `A3`).

Do you have any suggestions to avoid that or ideas for an alternative approach? As I said, it is all about performance I am asking.

I wrote a custom converter like the one described [here](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/converters.html), but it is simply returning no value in the `write_value()` method and if the value is `None` it still erases the cell's content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to read in the whole range, then change those values you want on the Python side and write it back. If your range contains formulas, you can use the `myrange.formula` property to read the formulas-it's ok to write them out via `.value` again. This way, you won't change existing cells.